Google Sign-In button (g_id_signin) - the icon is too close to text in RTL locales
I'm implementing Google Sign-In on my website and encountering an issue with the button layout in right-to-left (RTL) locales, specifically for Hebrew (he) and Arabic (sa).
The Google icon within the button appears too close to the text, without proper spacing. This creates an unbalanced and visually unappealing button:
  <div
      className="g_id_signin"
      data-type="standard"
      data-size="large"
      data-theme="outline"
      data-text="continue_with"
      data-shape="rectangular"
      data-logo_alignment="center"
      data-locale="he"> <!-- or "ar_SA" for Arabic -->
</div>

Output:


Is there a way to adjust the spacing between the icon and text using the available Google Sign-In button parameters? If not, are there any workarounds or alternative implementations that maintain the official Google branding while allowing for proper RTL layout?

create your own Google button

@HezyZiv Do you suggest from experience?

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

Please don't use https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button. That library is deprecated

Could you provide more information on your environment? I tried it on Chrome, Firefox, Safari on Mac, but I was able to see the a space between the text and the G logo.
